# Laravel query for showing records starting soonest but not records where date has passed

Tags: laravel

I'm a little new so I only know the basics. I have a course table where it has the start_date of a course (timestamp) and  I would like to show the courses starting closes to the current date but not courses that have passed (e.g yesterdays courses).

I also need to not do this with a scope.

My model is App\Course. My current code is

```
$course = Course::latest()->take(6)->get());
```

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is there even a `latest` function on the query builder? I would think that you'd have to use an `->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')` if you wanted them sorted. Also, look into the usage of `->whereDate()` to limit the results to any date after today.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll take a look into that. But yeah, latest() does the created_at, desc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$course = Course::where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now())->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')->take(6)->get());
```

It will work if you'll add `start_date` to a [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) variable.

Comment: I would go with `'>='` or you wont see courses of today